# Find a suitable continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> Find a continuous function from $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}, \{7, 8\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these (call it $T$), and $\mathbb N$ with topology $\{1, 3\}, \{2, 4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6, 8\}, \{9, 11\}, \{10, 12\}, \ldots$ and all unions of these(call it $T'$).

Consider $f(x) = \cases{x \text{ if }x \pmod 4 = 0 \text{ or } 1 \\ x + 1 \text{ if } x \pmod 4 = 2 \\ x - 1 \text{ if } x \pmod 4 = 3}$

Let $O \in T'$.

We have $f(x) \in O \implies x \in f^{-1}(O)$.

Now,

$1. \ f(x) = x \implies x = 4q$ or $x = 4q + 1$ for some natural $q$. Then $x \in \mathbb N$. Thus $f^{-1}(O) \subseteq \mathbb N.$

$2. \ f(x) = x - 1 \implies x = 4q + 3 \in \mathbb N$  for some natural $q$ and so $f^{-1}(O) \subseteq \mathbb N.$

$3. \ f(x) = x+ 1 \implies x = 4q + 2 \in \mathbb N$  for some natural $q$ and so $f^{-1}(O) \subseteq \mathbb N.$

Granted $T$ contains every possible subset of $\mathbb N,$ it follows, $f^{-1}(O) \in T$ and so $f^{-1}(O)$ is open meaning $f$ is continuous.

---

My questions:

- Does the fact that I have to choose $q$ in the cases above to be a natural(and not just an integer) mean $f(x)$ is defined incorrectly? Would the following definition fix the problem?

  $f(x) = \cases{x \text{ if }x = 4q \text{ or } x = 4q + 1 \text{ for some } q \in \mathbb N \\ x + 1 \text{ if } x =4q + 2 \text{ for some } q \in \mathbb N \\ x - 1 \text{ if } x = 4q + 3 \text{ for some } q \in \mathbb N}$
- Does $T$ contain every possible subset of $\mathbb N?$
- Would the proof above be correct if the modified $f(x)$ is correct and $T$ does contain every possible subset of $\mathbb N?$

Thanks.

edit: context for this question is that I am trying to find a homeomorphism between $(\mathbb N, T), (\mathbb N, T').$ So far can't seem to be able to.

Comment: $T$ doesn't contain every subset—consider $\{1\}$ or $\{1,2,3\}$ for example. By the way, although your answer is more interesting, note that any constant function is already continuous (regardless of the specific topologies) and thus technically answers the question asked.

Comment: @GregMartin, would a constant function work as a homeomorphism between $(\mathbb N, T)$ and $(\mathbb N, T')?$

Comment: Definitely not a homeomorphism!—but the wording in the OP doesn't say "homeomorphism", only "continuous function".